# How to solve "cannot set property of undefined" on JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a "chess game" on JS and I have to make something like this. Everything goes normal when I run the code, but on the console I get the message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined at func". What should I do to solve this? Because it is delaying the page.

```js
let obj = {
  value: 50
}

function func (object) {
  setTimeout(func);
  object.value = 10;
}

func(obj);
```

Everything goes normal, but the console says something is wrong. What do I do?

Comment: `setTimeout(func);` calls your `func` without passing `object`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `setTimeout` expects a duration. Plus, you're not passing the object to it. Once you get this working the function will keep calling itself forever... Is that what you want?

Comment: Could you explain what is your intention here?

Answer (score 2):

Your timer callback isn't passing anything to the `func` function. So, when `func` runs as a result of the timer, there are no parameters, so `object` is `undefined`.

**You'll need to wrap it in an anonymous function that can pass `object` to it.**

```js
let obj = {
 value: 50
}

function func (object) {
  setTimeout(function() { func(object); });
  object.value = 10;
}

func(obj);
```

Comment: The arguments are reversed.

Comment: Still creating an infinite loop.

Comment: @connexo Of course it is. The timer is self referential. This is essentially the same as using an interval. But, that wasn't the point of the post.

Comment: Given the obvious level of proficiency of OP, that's an essential point-out.

Comment: @connexo I disagree. I think that was then entire point of the post - - figuring out why the callback was failing.

Comment: This is an infinite asynchronous loop, the browser can handle that :) I think OP didn't even write his exit statement yet before he encountered the issue he is having now.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you don't even need to pass `obj` to `func()`; as `obj` is defined outside the function, scope dictates that it is available without passing.

```js
let obj = {
  value: 50
}

function func () {
  setTimeout(func);
  obj.value = 10;
}

func();
```

Note: the `setTimeout(func)` inside `func()` causes an infinite loop (as pointed out in answers/comments), but as far as why you're getting the error, this is an approach to solve that.

Comment: I think the point of the question was why the code, as written fails, not really to find an alternate way to code this.

Comment: Fair, but other answers (namely yours) have already pointed out the logic error on `setTimeout()` with an anonymous function, so if I had posted that, it would be pointless. There's no harm in posting another approach.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` takes 2 parameters: The function to call, and the delay in milliseconds.

```
let obj = {
  value: 50
}

function func (object) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    func(object);
  }, 0); // how long should it wait?
  object.value = 10;
}

func(obj);
```

Comment: If your plan was to use a closure, it has to be `func(object)` inside your `setTimeout` predicate.

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't require 2 parameters though. You can omit the delay if you want.

Comment: delay is in milliseconds. Also its only a minimum, not a guaranteed, exact delay.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout(func);` calls your `func` without passing `object`. Simply remove it (it's even **harmful** as explained below):

```js
let obj = {
  value: 50
}

function func(object) {
  object.value = 10;
}

func(obj);
console.log(obj.value);
```

As it currently stands, using it doesn't create any value anyway, **but it creates an infinite loop.**

Comment: It's not essentially harmful as this is a common approach to doing animations. It's essentially an interval. But, this technique is more efficient than with interval.

Comment: I cannot consider any code that creates infinite looping a *common approach* for whatever problem. That's just really, **really** bad coding.

Comment: Uh, no it's not. It's how constant movement would be animated. It's extremely common. We're talking about asynchronous callbacks here. It's the exact same functionality as `setInterval`.

Comment: @connexo I understand your concern but `while(true)` is perfectly fine. In generators it is even a common pattern. We don't know if we are looking at finished code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It's not identical, as it stands there's no way to `stopInterval`.

Comment: It is identical because when you use an Interval, there's no automatic way to stop it either. You have to set up a `clearInterval()`. In fact, based on a whitepaper I read some time ago, using a self-referential timer, instead of an interval is actually more efficient and really is a very common approach.